# Not Scrolling Properly

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling

I've been trying to figure out why it wont scroll. This issue only arises with Google Chrome. I'm assuming it has to do with some sort of depreciation.

http://www.keywestvideographer.net/

Previously when you clicked on About or Contact it would scroll to that section of the page.

plugins.js:24 [Intervention] Registering mousewheel event as passive due to smoothscroll.js usage. The smoothscroll.js library is buggy, no longer necessary and degrades performance. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5749447073988608

I went ahead and edited plugin.js and did what the instructions said on chromestatus.com but it didnt solve the issue.

Any idea why it wont scroll or what needs to be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your JS error first and test again.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined"
```

Edit: You have the error on both FF and Chrome. The reason that it dont work on Chrome, but works on FF is that Chrome is treating it as a breaking error, while FF is just catching the error and proceeding through the script.

The error relates to revslider. It seems it is looking for an element that does not exist on your page.

You have your JS minified, so I cant really debug past that point.

Comment: Not sure what it could be. It works perfectly on any other brother except Google